# How can I exclude arrays and objects without excluding null values in a jq filter?

Tags: json, jq

I don't understand why, when filtering out all items that are objects and arrays, null values are affected as well.

And I didn't find any workaround so far.

The input:

```
$ cat test.json
{
  "object": {
    "key1": 1,
    "key2": null,
    "key3": 3
  },
  "array": [ "a", null, "c" ]
}
```

Actual behavior, unexpectedly missing output for null values:

```
$ jq '[ paths(select(type | IN("object", "array") | not)) as $path | { "\($path)": getpath($path) } ] | add' test.json
{
  "[\"object\",\"key1\"]": 1,
  "[\"object\",\"key3\"]": 3,
  "[\"array\",0]": "a",
  "[\"array\",2]": "c"
}
```

Desired (and expected) output:

```
{
  "[\"object\",\"key1\"]": 1,
  "[\"object\",\"key2\"]": null,
  "[\"object\",\"key3\"]": 3,
  "[\"array\",0]": "a",
  "[\"array\",1]": null,
  "[\"array\",2]": "c"
}
```

EDIT:

As we can see here, paths with null values are output if no filter is applied:

```
$  jq '[ paths as $path | { "\($path)": getpath($path) } ] | add' test.json
{
  "[\"object\"]": {
    "key1": 1,
    "key2": null,
    "key3": 3
  },
  "[\"object\",\"key1\"]": 1,
  "[\"object\",\"key2\"]": null,
  "[\"object\",\"key3\"]": 3,
  "[\"array\"]": [
    "a",
    null,
    "c"
  ],
  "[\"array\",0]": "a",
  "[\"array\",1]": null,
  "[\"array\",2]": "c"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`paths/1` (see its [definition](https://github.com/jqlang/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L52)) already applies `select/1` using your provided node filter. Your approach didn't work because your node filter also applies another `select/1` around the result, causing *falsy* values (`null` and `false`) being filtered out. Remove your `select/1` from the node filter, and it'll work:

```bash
[ paths(type | IN("object", "array") | not) as $path
  | { "\($path)": getpath($path) }
] | add
```

```json
{
  "[\"object\",\"key1\"]": 1,
  "[\"object\",\"key2\"]": null,
  "[\"object\",\"key3\"]": 3,
  "[\"array\",0]": "a",
  "[\"array\",1]": null,
  "[\"array\",2]": "c"
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/mbUYeIbPwUM)

---

Alternatively, especially if you were including `select/1` to simulate the application of [shortcuts](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#arrays-objects-iterables-booleans-numbers-normals-finites-strings-nulls-values-scalars) like `iterables/0` (selecting only arrays and objects), or `scalars/0` (the opposite), which themselves are also all [implemented](https://github.com/jqlang/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L54-L64) based on `select/1` (thus not usable here with `paths/1`), you could switch to the non-recursive `path/1` [filter](https://jqplay.org/s/Ke6H7XHpfpd) (no "s"), and manually include the recursion, e.g. using the [recursive descent](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#recursive-descent) `..`:

```bash
[ path(.. | select(type | IN("object", "array") | not)) as $path
  | { "\($path)": getpath($path) }
] | add

# or

[ path(.. | scalars) as $path
  | { "\($path)": getpath($path) }
] | add
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Ke6H7XHpfpd)

---

Depending on your specific use-case, you might also be interested in jq's feature to convert its input into a "stream representation" which already provides you with a `[path, value]` structure, using the `tostream/0` filter or the `--stream` option. Just filter out the backtracking items (without value) by selecting by index 1.

```bash
jq '[tostream | select(has(1)) | {("\(first)"): last}] | add'
# or
jq --stream -s 'map(select(has(1)) | {("\(first)"): last}) | add'
# or
jq --stream -n 'reduce (inputs | select(has(1))) as [$p,$v] ({}; .["\($p)"] = $v)'
```

Comment: Although I still don't fully understand, why my approach doesn't work, I find your solution much better, simpler and clearer!
Also the solutions that use the stream representations are amaying.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: To be more clear regarding what I don't understand:
Why isn't the negation of `type | in ("object", "array")` true for type "null"?

Comment: @yaccob `paths/1` is [defined](https://github.com/jqlang/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L56) already using a `select` with your custom filter. Your approach didn't work because you wrapped another `select` around it, resulting in filtering out *falsy* values (`null` and `false`). Remove your `select`, and it'll work: `[ paths(type | IN("object", "array") | not) as $path | …`

Comment: @yaccob Got confused myself: Using `scalars` ([defined](https://github.com/jqlang/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L64) as `select(type|. != "array" and . != "object")`) has of course the same issue (filtering out `false` values), so I replaced this entire part of the answer with the content of the last comment.

Comment: now I understand the problem, I learned a lot from your clear answers, thank you very much